# How to connect to my web host via SSH

Tags: ssh

I need to connect to my web host via SSH. I created a public and private SSH key on the web host then downloaded the private key (id_rsa). I have no idea where I should put the private key on my computer or what the proper SSH command should look like. I've searched the web but everything I've found is confusing. I'm running a recent version of Linux Mint (Ubuntu based). Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create both keys locally, and only move the public key. The private key is private, it should be known by only one device. But if you can completely trust the remote, or if you will not use the key for anything else, and you transferred it securely, then it does not matter.

## The private key goes in local

The private key goes in `~/.ssh`, on the local machine.
You can load it with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/keyname`, if you use default names then `ssh-add` is enough.

## The public key goes in the remote

```
#do once
mkdir ~/.ssh/public-keys
cp -t ~/.ssh/public-keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

#do for each key
cp -t ~/.ssh/public-keys the-public-key
cat ~/.ssh/public-keys/* >~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```